# How to create quizzes with macqtex?

Tags: teaching

I found a beautiful example of a powerful quiz that was created using LaTeX: http://www.tug.org/texshowcase/macqtexDemo.pdf

This example uses JavaScript inside a PDF document. Unfortunately, **there is no source available**. Does anyone know where I can find it?

P.S. Maybe there are similar packages you can advise?

Comment: You may better look in to the `acrotex` bundle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You asked for the packages... Well the link you provided is prepared using the `exerquiz` package from `The AcroTEX eDucation Bundle (AeB)`. Following is a screen shot from the `aeb` manual.
[image]

For more details do a `texdoc acrotex` from the command line.

**EDIT:** The links for sample files as given by the `aeb` manual are:

1. http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/webeq_ex.html
2. [Example Files for AeB](http://www.math.uakron.edu/~dpstory/aebblog.html)

This is a screen shot from manual again showing the links:

[image]

Comment: There are many similar examples at [http://user.mendelu.cz/marik/?item=42] - each PDF file has embedded TeX source on the first page. I also tested the cooperation of acrotex with Luatex which is not mentioned in manual and it wors.